# How to copy a clipping mask in illustrator without both the copies not being linked to each other?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, mask

I tried copying the clipping mask by holding alt and dragging the mask, but when I "release" one mask, both the masks are released.

Is there a way to copy the path I created with the pen tool? I want to use the same path as the opacity mask in other location on the same artboard.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am new to illustrator.

Comment: Hey Vikrant, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends a lot on *how* a clipping mask is created.

You can have layer-level clipping masks which mask everything on that layer. Layer-level clipping masks are created by selecting a path and choosing the `Make Clipping Mask` from the **Layers Panel Menu**. What this does is mask **everything** on that layer based on the designated shape.

An object-level clipping mask is created by selecting more than one shape and then choosing `Object > Clipping Path > Make`. This creates a *clip group* where only objects within the group are masked by the designated shape. (Using the "draw inside" mode creates object-level clipping masks as well.)

I don't know the under-the-hood specifics of how it technically varies, but I do know it varies. There's no way to tell which you have other than looking at the layers panel:

[image]

Note the `Clip Group` in the object level mask.

You can have **as many object-level** clipping masks as you desire on any layers. There's basically no limitation.

However, you can have **only one layer-level** clipping mask per layer.

**So in short, you need to construct things with Object-level masks, not layer-level masks.**

Note: Simply dragging the clipping path outside a clip group *does not* create a layer-level mask. And conversely dragging a layer-level clipping mask into a group does *not* create a clip group. Although logically you would think it should. This is a difference at the *point of creation* which can not easily be "swapped" when dealing with existing objects.